# Angular calling cloud function multiple times

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm having problems with a cloud function being called multiple times in my angular project. So `console.log('call')` is being executed three times.

```
this.profileList$ = this.usersService.profileList(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('groupId')!).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('call')),
      catchError(() => {
        this.toastrService.danger('You do not have permission to view this group', 'Error');
        return of([]);
      }),
    );
```

I tried to use `take(1)`but made no difference, it seems that it has something to do with when I handle my `profileList$`, because if I delete my `fieldsToSearch$` I'll have one call less, and if I delete my async pipe in .html I'll have another one less.
But of course, if I delete `fieldsToSearch$` and the async pipe it'll break.

```
this.fieldsToSearch$ = this.profileList$.pipe(
      map((profiles) =>
        profiles.map((profile: any) => {
          const formattedProfile = { ...profile };
          formattedProfile.values = [ formattedProfile.displayName ];
          // Append sortedField values to values array
          for (const field of formattedProfile.sortedFields) {

 KEEPS GOING JUST FORMATTING DATA
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about caching the response and providing it to the late subscribers from that cache:

```js
import { publishReplay, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.profileList$ = this.usersService.profileList(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('groupId')!).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('call')),
      catchError(() => {
        this.toastrService.danger('You do not have permission to view this group', 'Error');
        return of([]);
      }),
      publishReplay(1),
      refCount(),
    );
```